# How to make abc.com/def secure to not open the webpages inside directly without authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a Default.aspx.cs file which is called when http://blah.com loads first. In this file - after user authentication and based on user access privilege I'm redirecting to other webpage I have viz.

1) Response.Redirect("~/readonly.aspx");

2) Response.Redirect("~/write.aspx");

The issue is that when I do a http://www.blah.com then the flow first goes to the login page which is what it ideally should do. But if I do a http://blah.com/write then I can directly access that webpage without the user authentication done first.

What can I do on the web server side (IIS) or in the code itself to handle this?

Comment: are you using any MasterPages..? also you can handle this by creating something like this in your `Global.asax` page for the `OnSession_Start` event `HttpContext.Current.Session["isValidUser"] = false;` then in each of the `Page_Load` events you can check if they value is `true || false` if false issue the Redirect("~/Login.aspx");`

Comment: you need to write your own authorization method for keeping track.. this is not that difficult.. if you were using MasterPages then on it's `Page_Load` even the checking can be done there because before any of the other pages render / pre-render the master pages Page_Load event gets hits all the time try it along with putting breakpoints and you will see

Comment: This is my Global.asax currently - how should I rewrite this file to include authentication?

<%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ASP.Global" Language="C#" %>

Comment: you write the code in the `Global.asax.cs` file I just gave you an example and where to put it to initialize the session variable then you need to assign it based on the successful login or not..